# What is the probability of collision in Hash Function?

Tags: hash, cryptography, hash-function, cryptographic-hash-function

I want to ask about the probability of collision in Hash Function?

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to applaud the amount of effort you have put into your question.

Comment: is there any differences between the Preimage attack and Second attack?

Comment: That just might depend on which hash function don't you think?

Comment: like, md5 for example

Comment: I bet the wikipedia article on MD5 goes into depth on that subject and I also bet that when it mentions preimage attacks it links to another document describing preimage attacks

Answer (score 5):

The probability of collision in a hash function which *uniformly* distributes k inputs to N possible hash values is:

[image]

[Source](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities)

Comment: +1 Nice source... Not a great question but pleased the OP has a constructive response to work with.